# NoMethodError when calling a Model method in an RSpec test

Tags: ruby, rspec, tdd

I'm writing a script to automatically sort files on my computer, like screenshots. I'm on a Mac. So whenever I snap a screenshot, it's created on my desktop. Part of the script's purpose is to clean up the desktop from time to time.

Most Ruby scripts that I've seen are classless (har har), but I've decided to class mine up so I can use RSpec and TDD to test everything as I go, practice my RGR loop.

I receive this error when running an RSpec test on a method called 'chdir' in a class called 'Mover':

```
Failures:

  1) Mover#chdir changes the directory
   Failure/Error: chdir(@mover.target_dir)

 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `chdir' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Mover::Chdir:0x007ffae608f898> # ./spec/models/mover_spec.rb:18:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

The code itself:

```
class Mover
  $home = Dir.home

  attr_accessor :file_type, :working_dir, :target_dir

  def initialize(file_type, working_dir, target_dir)
    @file_type = file_type
    @working_dir = working_dir
    @target_dir = target_dir
  end

  def chdir(dir)
  end


end

mover = Mover.new("/Screen Shot\s\d*.\d*.\d*\sat\s.*.png/g", "Desktop", "/Desktop/screenshots")
```

Then the spec:

```
describe Mover do
  before do
    @mover = Mover.new("/Screen Shot\s\d*.\d*.\d*\sat\s.*.png/g", "Desktop", "/Desktop/screenshits")
  end

  describe "#initialize" do
    it "Initializes the object." do
      expect( @mover.class.name ).to eq("Mover")
    end
  end

  describe "#chdir" do
    it "changes the directory" do
      #chdir(@mover.target_dir)
    end
  end

end
```

The offending line is commented out. I'm honestly stumped as to why this is happening. Any help would be appreciated.

Link to github repo, just in case: https://github.com/swolegrammer/ruby-file-mover

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to use `@mover.chdir` instead. I would use `subject` instead of `before { @mover = Mover.new ... }`.

Regarding the use of let vs subject vs before I would suggest to have a read on this rspec-style-guide issue: https://github.com/reachlocal/rspec-style-guide/issues/6.

```
describe Mover do
  subject(:mover) { Mover.new("/Screen Shot\s\d*.\d*.\d*\sat\s.*.png/g", "Desktop", "/Desktop/screenshits") }

  describe "#initialize" do
    it "Initializes the object." do
      expect(mover.class.name).to eq("Mover")
    end
  end

  describe "#chdir" do
    it "changes the directory" do
      mover.chdir(mover.target_dir)
    end
  end
end
```